# Reconnect to oracle db after restart from Wildfly datasource

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, datasource, wildfly

I have a product that uses Wildfly datasource to connect to Oracle DB.
Our Database servers have a scheduled weekly cold backup and for this reason the DB will shutdown every week for approx 10 mins. Then i am forced to restart the application after the DB is started.

How do i configure my Wildfly datasource to check and reconnect after the db is started ?

Wildfly version: wildfly-8.2.0.Final

Data source configuration -

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/REQUESTDS" pool-name="REQUESTDS" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MYDB</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <connection-property name="selectMethod">
                        direct
                    </connection-property>
                    <connection-property name="sendStringParametersAsUnicode">
                        true
                    </connection-property>
                    <driver>oracle-thin</driver>
                    <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</new-connection-sql>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>80</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <security-domain>CompanySecureDataSource</security-domain>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>90000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <allocation-retry>40</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>30000</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
```

I have checked my threads here and tried most of them. But in vain.

What is the correct setting that will check and reconnect to oracle db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `background-validation` and the pool will try to create new connections if any one of them dies.

```
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>20000</background-validation-millis>
                </validation>
```

Comment: This works. Other related issue i found was if go to the jboss console and make the changes there. It doesnt get saved. So i had to open the standalone-full.xml and add these statements there. After a Restart it works. My Product is able to connect to the DB.